# Appium server returns "Error : Closed" with Code 1

Tags: appium, bluestacks

I am starting to use Appium Desktop for Mobile Testing. 
After the preliminary setup where I set the path and environment variables and defining the desired capabilities, clicking on "Start Session" button result in this message:

```
"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C\:\\Users\\test-PC\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.mol.molwallet' exited with code 1'; Stderr: 'error: closed'; Code: '1'.
```

Is there any way to find out what causes the "Closure" ? I am using Bluestack as the emulator.

Comment: Have you checked [appium-doctor](https://github.com/appium/appium-doctor)? Also, have you checked anywhere else in the log at appium?

Comment: @Alexis, sorry for the late reply. I have checked the log, but I'm afraid it's something I can't comprehend as I am new to appium. This is the [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1CmGir44rmDVw5TvYfOzuDnfCW3vUeUQb) to the screenshot of the log. Hope you can shed some light. I shall try appium-doctor as well, thanks

Comment: is your phone unlocked while trying this? Is the application installed? Is the package name ```com.mol.molwallet``` ok? Check [this link](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/) for package name.